# Multi-Site Open Source CMS?

Tags: open-source, cms, multi-user

[RespondCMS](http://respondcms.com) is an open source CMS/WYSIWYG website builder. It allows you to host a website builder and create your own templates. Visitors can then create their own websites using the templates you've previously made available and after a trial period pay a monthly fee to use their own domain name and gain access to advanced features.

Does anyone know of any others like this? Another established example is: http://share.ez.no/

What I'm looking for is a framework to use for my own small click-and-drag website builder business. My friends and I, around 10 of us, want to make hundreds of templates over the next few years.

Many thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3):

WordPress has exactly what you're looking for. It supports multi-site and with a few plugins, you can have all the features you need. Here is a list,

- [WordPress](https://wordpress.org/) with the [multisite feature](http://codex.wordpress.org/Glossary#Multisite) enabled
- Multiple domains with the plugin, [WordPress MU Domain Mapping](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-mu-domain-mapping/)
- Drag and drop interface with the plugin, [Page Builder by SiteOrigin](https://siteorigin.com/page-builder/)
- Above plugins and WordPress is completely open source

Answer (score 2):

[Rubedo](http://www.rubedo-project.org/en/homepage) is an open source multi-site CMS. It’s a perfect option for multiple websites:

- You can share content between sites
- Centralised administration
- In-line publishing capabilities
- Supports multi language